# Usbrip read from external syslog file

Tags: syslog

I want to examine usb violations with the usbrip tool ([usbrip github](https://github.com/snovvcrash/usbrip)) but the source log file which i want to read from is not the local system `syslog` file. Instead i have an external file.

When i follow the help menu and other examples online i'm left with this command:

```
usbrip events violations auth.json --file ./syslog
```

this should read all usb events and display any violations based on the `auth.json`.

But the output says that the tool is reading the system `journalctl` output and the result is my local system eventlog. Even though i specified my local syslog file with the `-f` argument.

[usbrip output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMfuf.png)

How can i read from the given syslog file and **not** the system one in `/var/log/syslog`?

Answer (score 1):

I found it out by myself. It seems to be a problem with the version of the tool. I installed an older version with

```
pip3 install usbrip==2.1.3.post3
```

and now it works.